# Set Access control in routing file like @Secure annotation above controller action

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following ACL settings in my secirity.yml file

```
    fos_user_resetting:
        path: /backend/request
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    super_admin_pages:
        path: /backend/.*
        roles: [ROLE_SUPER,ROLE_USERS]
```

Also i found setting access permission using @secirity tag in the routing annotation.

**My question is, is it possible to add security (access permission according to roles like in secirity.yml) for each path in routing.yml file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no such argument for securing routes directly in your routing file. The common part between ACL and routing are **paths**.

See all the details in the [Security chapter of Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).